# Serialize column always returning string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

I'm migrating a project from 2 to 2.3.18. I have a value column(col_type = text) which is serialized.when I store integer also its returning string. May I know what might be the issue.

I'm using mysql database.
ex:

```
>> a = AppSetting.last
=> #<AppSetting id: 1, name: "kranthi", value: "1", description: nil, created_at: "2013-08-26 12:17:47", updated_at: "2013-08-26 12:17:47">
>> a.value
=> "1"
>> a.value = 1
=> 1
>> a.save!
=> true
>> a = AppSetting.last
=> #<AppSetting id: 1, name: "kranthi", value: "1", description: nil, created_at: "2013-08-26 12:17:47", updated_at: "2013-09-01 14:28:21">
>> a.value
=> "1"
```

serialize :value

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your code! (Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.)

Comment: @Sumurai8 I edited my question and added example

Comment: Got the issue..in 2.3 serialize method internally changed so facing this issue